# configure nginx for MEAN stack

Tags: nginx, mean-stack

I heard that MEAN stack would be beneficial if it has nginx at front for some reasons and am following instructions from some people already done it. I installed MEAN stack via Bitnami and AWS and am trying to setting nginx configuration. I am modifying file /usr/share/nginx/default which contains this code.

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

My question is that should I have to put my address instead of 127.0.0.1?
and should I have to keep 3000 and change my AWS port setting? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`127.0.0.1` is a loopback ip address of the server, so the answer is no, you have to keep that ip address.

Port `3000` is an application port,that mean your application is listening on that port. Regularly, you can check port number that is in app.js or server.js files. You can change that port belong to port that you have set your application's port is listening. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: It's okay that English is not my first language neither. I don't have any setting for port 3000. I think I have to create setting in AWS page. Thank you!

Comment: After you deployed node application to the server, you have to run that application, for example, you run command: node app.js , that mean your application is to start listening on specify port that has set in your application code.

Comment: You just need set AWS security group for inpound port is 80.

Comment: It is set at 80 on AWS security group. how do I know I install nginx and configured successfully

Comment: you can see default nginx page at http://x.x.x.x  (with x.x.x.x is your public ip address of EC2 instance) if you're using AWS, it usually is : http://52.x.x.x or http://54.x.x.x

Comment: I typed my address which is 52.x.x.x and it worked. But in console, I restart nginx (sudo service nginx restart) and it failed to restart nginx. I only changed code 127.0.0.1:3000 -> 52.x.x.x:80 In AWS security group, I have 80 for http.  Did I miss anything?

Comment: I only changed code 127.0.0.1:3000 -> 52.x.x.x:80  : Change back to: 127.0.0.1:3000 and restart nginx.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:3000 restart nginx failed too. I don't think I made any typo.

Comment: show me some error log. tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: It shows " 4079#0: unknown directive "proxy_setheader" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:31" and [emerg] 18725#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use). let me research

Comment: 98: Address already in use: it mean : service nginx already running, you should kill running nginx process then start nginx again. Check line 31 not proxy_setheader, it's proxy_set_header

Comment: I check typo and it was not. I don't know why it shows setheader in error log. As you say something(I think MEAN stack) is using 80 port. ( In my security group in AWS port 80 is for http). I don't know how nginx take 80 and MEAN stack goes to 3000 port.